# How to keep matched row on top of other rows in " smart-table " irrespective of Pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smart-table

I'm using Smart table I want to keep matched rows on top of other rows in table using angularjs(1), in my case i have been matching string from table column, on the basis of matched string I'm changing row background color, and showing them on top of other row but **Problem is** ***those matched row not working as expected when I use smart table pagination***.

I want display all matched rows to top of other rows ***irrespective pagination*** and all using ***Smart-Table***

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('employeeController', function($scope) {

    var employees = [{
      "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "City": "Berlin",
      "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
      "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "City": "Luleå",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    }, {
      "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
      "City": "Mannheim",
      "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
      "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
      "City": "Strasbourg",
      "Country": "France"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
      "City": "Madrid",
      "Country": "Spain"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    }, {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    }, {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    }, {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    }, {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    }, {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    }, {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    }, {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    }, {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    }];
    $scope.employee = employees;
    $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.employee);
    $scope.itemsByPage = 10;

    var findme = "France";
    $scope.sort = (emp) => {
      emp.matched = emp.Country.indexOf(findme) > -1;
      return !emp.matched;
    }
  })
```

```css
.matched {
  background-color: #FFCCCB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.11/smart-table.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="employeeController">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:40px;">
      <div class="row">
        {{error}}
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table st-table="employees" st-safe-src="displayedCollection" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="emp in employee | orderBy: [sort, 'Name']" ng-class="{'matched': emp.matched }" ng-style="set_color(emp)">
                <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.City}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Country}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
                  <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```